# SQL Server query results sort order with totals

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to sort by the `ID` with the highest total. I can sort by ID and then get the total for each member but I cannot seem to get it to sort by id and total.

Below is what I have and what I want. On what I have I am doing

```
ORDER BY 
    1, 
    CASE WHEN DIAGN1 = 'TOTAL' THEN 'Z' END
```

Any suggestions on what I should do? Thanks.

```
WITH F3 AS
(
SELECT F2.ID
,F2.DIAGN1 
,F2.PROVIDER_NAME
,F2.FROM_DATE
,F2.DATE_TO
,F2.UNITS
,F2.TOTAL_PAID 
,F2.PER_DIEM
,F2.DW_PAID_DATE
FROM F2

UNION ALL

SELECT ID
,NULL DIAGN1 
,NULL PROVIDER_NAME
,NULL FROM_DATE
,NULL DATE_TO
,SUM(UNITS) AS UNITS
,SUM(TOTAL_PAID) AS TOTAL_PAID
,NULL PER_DIEM
,NULL DW_PAID_DATE
FROM F2
GROUP BY ID
)

,F4 AS
(
SELECT F3.ID
,CASE WHEN F3.DIAGN1 IS NULL THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE F3.DIAGN1 END AS DIAGN1
,F3.PROVIDER_NAME
,F3.FROM_DATE
,F3.DATE_TO
,F3.UNITS
,FORMAT(F3.TOTAL_PAID,'C','EN-US') AS TOTAL_PAID
,FORMAT(F3.PER_DIEM,'C','EN-US') AS PER_DIEM
,F3.DW_PAID_DATE 
FROM F3
)

SELECT F4.ID
,F4.DIAGN1
,F4.PROVIDER_NAME
,F4.FROM_DATE
,F4.DATE_TO
,F4.UNITS
,F4.TOTAL_PAID
,F4.PER_DIEM
,F4.DW_PAID_DATE 
FROM F4
ORDER BY 1, CASE WHEN DIAGN1 = 'TOTAL' THEN 'Z' END,3,4
```

[image]

Comment: Side note - you should discontinue using column numbers in `ORDER BY` as this will be discontinued.

Comment: really? i did not know. should i use column names then?

Comment: Do you have a citation for that, @squillman ? It's not in [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15). I'm not saying you shouldn't stop using `ORDER BY {Ordinal Position}`, just that I can't see a deprecation notice.

Comment: @Larnu I'll have to find it, but I did at one point which is why I quit using it other than for ad-hocs or short-term disposable code

Comment: @Larnu Hmm, yeah I must be confusing "don't use it - it's bad practice" with "it's going to be discontinued"...  I can't find anything either on it being deprecated.  Thanks for the fact-check :)

Comment: @sm86 Yes, column ordinals in `ORDER BY` are not good practice in general.  Best to use column names.

Comment: Thanks for checking @squillman . I know there's always one's that we miss, and I just wanted to make there wasn't something I'd missed in a (more recent) document. Perhaps you were just thinking of Bertrand's [Bad Habits to Kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal) article, as what he says is gospel most of the time. :)

Comment: @Larnu Could be, I know I've used Aaron's stuff as gospel in the past and that he does report depracations.  I haven't used ordinals in years now so who knows at this point...

Comment: @sm86 can you use dbfiddle.uk for create a [mcve] with some data to try? - I'm not sure if you can achieve your desired result with a sub-query...

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes how do I create that in dbfiddle? The data in the sample is what I used except for the total row.

Comment: @sm86 check this [sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=573cdcd719f03c0dda23c1b87e04a489), modify it by adding the data you're showing in those screenshots and press "run"; the URL will be updated.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Like this?[link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ec6a0a3c1adc015418cc96b543d1318)

Comment: @sm86 [yes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ce3cddd86efc75d1eebe40101b6d7b0) - just check the sample data you supplied is correct for testing, for example: in your screenshot is not clear why you sum F32.9 and F33.1; check the data and [edit] your question with the reasoning/logic of your sample data.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I'm not summing f32.9 and f33.1. Not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will give you what you want.

- We use `GROUPING SETS` to get the individual rows and the rolled-up `SUM`
- `GROUPING(F2.DIAGN1)` is `1` for the roll-up row only, in this case you can use any column
- Any column not in an aggregation returns `NULL` for the rolled-up row
- We order by a windowed `SUM`, you need to make sure to sum the sum, and partition also by `GROUPING`. The we order by `ID`, then by `GROUPING`

```sql
SELECT
     F2.ID
    ,CASE WHEN GROUPING(F2.DIAGN1) = 1 THEN 'TOTAL' ELSE F2.DIAGN1 END AS DIAGN1
    ,F2.PROVIDER_NAME
    ,F2.FROM_DATE
    ,F2.DATE_TO
    ,SUM(F2.UNITS) UNITS
    ,FORMAT(SUM(F2.TOTAL_PAID),'C','EN-US') AS TOTAL_PAID
    ,FORMAT(F2.PER_DIEM,'C','EN-US') AS PER_DIEM
    ,F2.DW_PAID_DATE
FROM F2
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (
     F2.ID
    ,F2.DIAGN1 
    ,F2.PROVIDER_NAME
    ,F2.FROM_DATE
    ,F2.DATE_TO
    ,F2.UNITS
    ,F2.TOTAL_PAID 
    ,F2.PER_DIEM
    ,F2.DW_PAID_DATE
  ),
  (
     F2.ID
  )
)
ORDER BY
  SUM(SUM(F2.TOTAL_PAID)) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, GROUPING(F2.DIAGN1)) DESC
, ID
, GROUPING(F2.DIAGN1)
, PROVIDER_NAME
, FROM_DATE;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1312047b219114a5123254e591e05de3)

Comment: Thank you. It worked but is smallest to largest. I put DESC at end of the first order by line and that was it. Thanks again for the great explanation and teaching something new to me. Is it possible to have another column where if the total_paid was >=50k then yes or to divide the total_paid by units?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you are asking, but you should probably create a new question for that